# Use SQL Script Parameter to Map Drive

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to map a drive to a UNC path where the UNC Path is a variable, but I keep getting an error saying:

> Incorrect syntax near '+'

I execute this script:

```
DECLARE @UNCSourcePath nvarchar(255) = '\\OTHER_SERVER\C$\Program Files'
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'NET USE S: ' + @UNCSourcePath
```

Any idea what the syntax should be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it only accepts one argument. So try doing this...

```
DECLARE @UNCSourcePath nvarchar(255) = 'NET USE S: "\\OTHER_SERVER\C$\Program Files"'  
EXEC xp_cmdshell @UNCSourcePath
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to run this on a SQL 2005 Instance since my newer instances do not allow xp_cmdshell execution, which is why the parameters do not have their initial values set with the declare statements.  I added a second parameter and then executed that.  Remove the comments from the --EXEC (@MappingCommand) statement to execute it.

```
    DECLARE @UNCSourcePath  nvarchar(255),
            @MappingCommand nvarchar(500)

    SELECT @UNCSourcePath = '\\OTHER_SERVER\C$\Program Files'''

    SELECT @MappingCommand = 'EXEC xp_cmdshell ' + '''NET USE S: ' +     @UNCSourcePath

    SELECT @MappingCommand

    --EXEC (@MappingCommand)
```